# FFMpeg takes up the whole cpu and spams log on bug encounter

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, png, mp4

I have FFMpeg working on backend of website converting image + music to video. Every once in a while (probably 1/200 files), someone uploads something and cpu is always at 100% spamming error into log and filling up the whole space on drive, making the app unusable.

I have literally at least a bilion lines of this in log

```
[png @ 0x50f0700] Invalid PNG signature 0x2020202020202020.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Here is an example of command that caused it this time :

```
ffmpeg -y -v error -loop 1 -r 1 -i image.png -i song.mp3 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -vf scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2 -preset ultrafast -r 1 -shortest output.mp4
```

What can I do if I don't have a control over files that get converted ?

Comment: Add `-xerror` to exit upon any error, like the one shown here.

Comment: Post your files, which causes errors

Comment: @bukkojot I don't have a file, I do not keep them. I tried contacting user for it and waiting. I only know that it's png.

Comment: @RobertVangor, it very hard to reproduce problem without there files. In my practice was issue, where simple mp3 file crashed whole server, which worked fine for years. Only detail debug with problem mp3 file make possible to find bug.